# Weird flicker in jQuery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a weird problem and i cant find a solution no matter what i tried.
I have a simple menu that toggles few divs (slide up/down), like this:

```
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul class="left">
            <li><a href="#lorem1" class="menu">lorem1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#lorem2" class="menu">lorem2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#lorem3" class="menu">lorem3</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
```

and a few divs that are being toggled.Pretty simple but there is a lot of code, so i wont paste it here.

Script that makes it work is:

```
$('.navigation a').click(function() {
  var $requested = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
  $('.top-drawer').not($requested).slideUp('slow');
  $requested.slideToggle('slow')
});
```

Once the user clicks on the link, the div slides down more than it should, flickers and then it becomes the real height (the height is should be).

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n32bxhzb/). Please be sure to have the "Result" Window at at least 1000+ px wide otherwise it wont work (the error wont be shown).

Comment: I don't know the answer but I have an observation: if you replace 'slow' with a number like 5000 (for five seconds) you can see better what is happening.  It looks to me like jQuery just isn't handling a case when the two moving things are adjacent to each other.

Comment: It's a common problem, and it's (90% of the time) down to some CSS attribute. Check the likes of these questions for quick suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420315/jquery-ui-accordion-jumpy-when-opened

Comment: Your fiddle seems to run fine for me... I don't see any flickering.

Comment: I removed all of your `display` css styling and it now works fine, what is probably happening is you are using floats and display blocks, and when the height is changing the elements are moving around to fit which causes the height of the div which is sliding down / sliding up to change randomly. You will need to tackle your CSS to fix this issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand the code you are using.

This is the way I think jQuery's `slideUp()`, and `slideDown()` works; mainly the algorithm changes the `height` of the element, and `display` after the `height` is equal to the `height` of the element or at "0".

So when you will have your element's `position` set to `relative` you will see what you're calling "flickers", specially when you have multiple element at the same position. You will also see these "flickers" when you use `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()` etc, because the `display` of the element is not instantly set to "none" or anything visible in these cases, but after the animation completes.

Solution:

Set the element's position to absolute. That should solve your issue;
[example](https://jsfiddle.net/n32bxhzb/7/).

Comment: thanks for the help, but the main navigation needs to be pushed down once div slides, i cant use absolute positioning in this case

Comment: I just set the position of navigation to `absolute`, to create an easy example. The main focus is the elements you're sliding up and down. If you always want the navigation to be under the `div`s, or on top, or anywhere, you can have it wherever you want, and use CSS to style it the way you want. The example is meant to help you fix the issue in your question, everything else is just for example. Hope the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

See my suggestion on this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/n32bxhzb/8/)

Here an explanation of the changes in there:

#### The Problem

With all those floating elements inside each `.top-drawer` jQuery has a lot of issues calculating the height of the `div` because the elements will move around while sliding up and down.

#### Suggestion

Switching to `inline-block` instead. But for that to work with your CSS, particularly with the padding on each `.top-drawer`, you need to use `box-sizing: border-box;` on anything that is using `padding`, `inline-block` and `width` with **%**. If curious you can read about this [HERE](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

#### New problem

If you go the route of `inline-block` (best practice now). You will need to use jQuery 1.8.xx or higher. I noticed in your fiddle you use 1.7.2, which has a bug with `border-box` that was fixed in versions after that.